# Displaying WYSIWYG Editor in dynamic items from database as class

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

I am working on Quotation Module, where I can add single or n number of line items. Line item details like name, description, price are dynamically from item master. I'm using jquery for adding more than one item from the database.

For item description, I am trying to user CKEditor, which is working only for 1st item, not the other.

```js
$(".delete").on('click', function() {
  $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
  $('.check_all').prop("checked", false);
  check();
});
var i = $('table tr').length - 1;
$(".addmore").on('click', function() {
      count = $('table tr').length - 1;
      var data = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='productname_" + i + "' name='productname[]'/></td><input class='form-control' type='hidden' id='productcode_" + i + "' name='productcode[]'/> <td><textarea class='form-control ckeditor' id='description_" + i + "' name='description[]' ></textarea></td><td><input class='form-control price' type='text' id='price_" + i + "' name='price[]'/></td>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()" />
  </th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' class='case' /></td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productname_1" name="productname[]"></td>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="productcode_1" name="productcode[]">
    <td><textarea class="form-control ckeditor" id="description_1" name="description[]"></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control price" id="price_1" name="price[]"></td>
    <td><button type="button" class='btn btn-danger delete'>-</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class='btn btn-success addmore'>+ </button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I display CKEditor for all the line items?

Comment: OT: Missing an opening `<tr>` for your `<th>`s. In your second row you're missing some `<td>` around your inputs. And your `var data =` seems to be missing a closing `</tr>`.

Comment: Thanks! But even after correcting those, i did not the solution